# Is it efficient to query\update database at every transaction: Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am designing a real time book management system in java. So I need to save all users, books,  transactions in database(3 tables users, books, transactions). I have implemented JDBC for this.

So,  I would like to know which one is better among

1) Querying and updating database all the time, say I have to authenticate user from usertable or query for a book  from book table

OR

2) First query the database once application starts and store respective tables in Hashset  and iterate the HashSet while updating or querying and update all Hashset 's into database at the end of execution.

Comment: How often do you need to query or update? Unless your load is so high that you run into performance problems I'd just use the database. Caching data at startup introduces more complexity and potential bugs.

Comment: My guess is that JDBC would be a loser against Hibernate for his use case.  But I could be wrong ^ ^.

Comment: I would suggest using hibernate and cache on demand.

Comment: Yeah I know about ORM little bit. But I would like to use JDBC because of its simplicity.

Comment: @ThomasStets : Every time a user logs in and make some transaction. I need to update/query. So it is quite often.

Comment: @JavaGeek Using JDBC correctly actually _isn't_ that straightforward and there are many potential pitfalls.  This is one reason why ORM tools like Hibernate have become so popular for server-side Java.

Comment: @JavaGeek What do you consider "quite often"? Once every minute, or 100 times per second, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Gavin King is smiling at you somewhere.  There is an ORM (object relational model) tool called Hibernate, which was created exactly for the sort of use case you currently have.  Using Hibernate, you would create Java objects representing the tables, users, books, and transactions in your database schema.  As you execute your business logic, these objects would get updated.  You can decide where and when you want to sync up with the database by controlling the size and scope of each transaction (session).  When you want to synchronize with the database, you can call the `flush()` method.

The answer to your question is that it depends on many factors.  In general, you want to avoid churning your database, so the size and scope of your database transactions should be created around this.